Beamer exam with generated solutions
I'm trying to automate small exams in Beamer class.
They are supposed to:

Have a command for question and answer like: \question{43-1=}{42}
Enumerate all question on separate slides
Summarize all questions on the following slide
Display the questions again individually but this time with a complete question-answer slide in between.
Summarize all questions with answers.

This is what I got so far:
    \documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor} % Needed for the foreach loop
\usepackage{xstring} % Provides string manipulation macros
\usepackage{amsmath} % For mathematical symbols

% Remove special characters (like quotes) from the filename
\title{\StrSubstitute{\jobname}{"}{}}

\author{Your Name}
\date{\the\year} % Only display the current year

% Store solutions in a macro with pauses
\newcommand{\solutions}{}
\newcommand{\addsolution}[1]{\expandafter\def\expandafter\solutions\expandafter{\solutions\item #1\par\pause}}

% Define questions with pause to show incrementally
\newcommand{\questions}{
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Solve \(x^2 - 4 = 0\)
        \pause
        \item \only<2>{Integrate \(\int x^2 \, dx\)}
        \pause
        \item \only<3>{Differentiate \(f(x) = \sin(x)\)}
        \pause
        \item \only<4>{Find the limit \(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\)}
    \end{enumerate}
}

% Define solutions
\addsolution{\(x^2 - 4 = 0 \Rightarrow x = \pm 2\)}
\addsolution{\(\int x^2 \, dx = \frac{x^3}{3} + C\)}
\addsolution{\(\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \cos(x)\)}
\addsolution{\(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1\)}

\begin{document}
    
    % Title page
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    % Frame with questions appearing one by one
    \begin{frame}{Mathematical Questions}
        \questions % Display each question individually
    \end{frame}
    
    % Overview of solutions
    \begin{frame}{Solutions}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \solutions % Display all solutions with pauses
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}

The \pause does not seem to help.
I found something similar here maybe you know of more examples or can help me out.

What do you mean by "summarize all questions"?

Providing an overview of all questions on a single slide.
